# How exclude in fileset checking if property is set?

Tags: ant, build

I need to create a fileset but I need to exclude a folder if some property is set (project.name).

```
<fileset dir="${build.folder}">
                <include name="**/*"/>
                <exclude name="${project.name}/**/*"/>
</fileset>
```

How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are using a recent version of ANT (1.9.1+), try this:

```
<project name="tryit" xmlns:if="ant:if" xmlns:unless="ant:unless">
    <target name="try">
        <fileset id="my-fileset" dir="${build.folder}">
            <include name="**/*"/>
            <exclude if:set="project.name" name="${project.name}/**/*"/>
        </fileset>
        <echo message="My fileset is ${toString:my-fileset}" />
    </target>
</project>
```

Comment: I am receiving "The prefix "if" for attribute "if:set" associated with an element type "exclude" is not bound"

Comment: I get the same message when I remove the `xmlns:if="ant:if" xmlns:unless="ant:unless"` section from my example. Did you add that to the project tag?

Comment: Just to note, [`<exclude>` has its own attributes confusingly also called `if` and `unless`](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/patternset.html). So, you could remove the `xmlns:if="ant:if" xmlns:unless="ant:unless"` part and replace `if:set="project.name"` with just `if="project.name"`. This reduces the verbosity of the script slightly.